# input file format for mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to machine learning. I am trying to use MLlib's decision tree.

Could somebody help me on how to prepare input file for mllib decision tree for multi category classification.

My csv file's has format of

Label, Text

```
label_1, text of label 1 
label_2, text of label 2 
label_3, text of label 3
```

Format required by mllib for input is libsvm, or labeledpoint.
 There are no text allowed in fileformat. Question is how to map text to numeric data based file format required by mllib, and later interpret results. I am using java for implementation.

Regards

Comment: Did you consider MLLib's TFIDF conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a mapper like this to parse the csv file

```
public class TokensToLabeledPoints implements Function<String[], LabeledPoint> {
int responseIndex;

TokensToLabeledPoints(int index) {
    this.responseIndex = index;
}

@Override
public LabeledPoint call(String[] tokens) throws Exception {
    double y = Double.parseDouble(tokens[responseIndex]);
    double[] x = new double[tokens.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
        if (responseIndex != i) {
            x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
    return new LabeledPoint(y, Vectors.dense(x));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

text to numeric is a wide and complex topic of [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model), [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). 
In general, you need:

1. create a new file without any class IDs (your original file - class info)
2. create a vocabulary  (set of words and its frequencies for each article)
3. based on original file, vocabulary:

   ```
   label_1, word1, word2,...
   label_2, word1, word2,...
   label_3, word1, word2,...
   ```
4. furthermore, based on the frequencies and math behind [TfxIdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) you might you create feature space (which usually gives better results than just bag of words)

   ```
   label_1, feature1, feature2,...
   label_2, feature1, feature2,...
   label_3, feature1, feature2,...
   ```

In Spark, look at: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf, or you might want to use tool like [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

good luck!